# Text coloring when "piping" output from Cucumber

Tags: ruby

I try to pipe the output from a command line command through Ruby.
It works fine but the coloring is missing.
How can I preserve the coloring?

This is what my code looks like:

```
cmd = "cucumber #{ARGV.join(" ")}"
IO.popen(cmd) do |io|
  io.each { |s| print s }
end
```

Updated:
The premise of the question was wrong - IO.popen **does** preserve the colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run cucumber with the `-c` option. Otherwise cucumber determines that the terminal (the pipe) does not support coloring and will drop it if not explicitly forced on with `-c`.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/blob/master/lib/cucumber/cli/options.rb#L211

```
...
opts.on("-c", "--[no-]color",
        "Whether or not to use ANSI color in the output. Cucumber decides",
        "based on your platform and the output destination if not specified.")
...
```

Comment: Awesome. I just updated the title and added a comment to the question.